# Scrapy crawl stopping too early and obtaining URL's outside the regex expression

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, scrapy, transcription

Goal: Scrape the soap opera transcript website  to obtain a corpus of transcripts.  The transcripts are in pages of the form http://tvmegasite.net/transcripts/amc/main/2001transcripts.shtml
and have the regular expression:

```
(https?:\/\/?tvmegasite\.net\/transcripts\/\w+\/main\/\d+\w+\.\w+)
```

1) **Question 1:** From result #1, it is clear I haven't done enough to follow links to get to stage 4, (that is, to get to something that looks like http://tvmegasite.net/transcripts/theshow/main/,)
which will contain the desired transcript pages of the regex form above. The spider stops following links at some point instead of continuing to the end. So what's the best way to to keep following links until I get to the desired form?

2) **Question 2:**
When I tried to test how well the scraper was working despite this, by starting the scraping for example, at http://tvmegasite.net/amc/main, I don't get a list of just the html transcripts, but a bunch of other links, many of which don't satisfy the regex expression.  I know my regex is correct so what is going on?

My code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from soapoperascrape.items import SoapoperascrapeItem

class SoapOperaSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name="S_O_"
    allowed_domains=["tvmegasite.net"]
    start_urls=["http://tvmegasite.net/transcripts"]
    rules=(Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('https?://tvmegasite\.net/transcripts/\w+/main/\d+\w+\.\w+', )), callback='parse_dir_contents'),)

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs=Selector(response)
        for href in hxs.xpath('/html/body/pre/a/@href'):
            url=response.urljoin(href.extract())
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_dir_contents)

    def parse_dir_contents(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('/html/body/pre'):
            item=SoapoperascrapeItem()
            item['link']=sel.xpath('a/@href').extract()
            yield item
```

Result #1:

```
[{"link": ["?N=D", "?M=A", "?S=A", "?D=A", "/transcripts/", "localresources/", "main/", "older/"]},
{"link": ["?N=D", "?M=A", "?S=A", "?D=A", "/transcripts/", "localresources/", "main/", "older/"]},
{"link": ["?N=D", "?M=A", "?S=A", "?D=A", "/transcripts/", "localresources/", "main/", "older/"]},
{"link": ["?N=D", "?M=A", "?S=A", "?D=A", "/transcripts/", "localresources/", "main/", "older/"]},
{"link": ["?N=D", "?M=A", "?S=A", "?D=A", "/transcripts/", "localresources/", "main/", "older/"]},
{"link": ["?N=D", "?M=A", "?S=A", "?D=A", "/transcripts/", "blueprnt/", "clearday/", "dpawin/", "expeditn/", "nature/", "strtedge/", "sumipntg/", "themes.inf", "tp-dis4/", "tp-mod2/", "tp-pnt9/"]},
{"link": ["?N=D", "?M=A", "?S=A", "?D=A", "/transcripts/", "localresources/", "main/", "older/"]},
{"link": ["?N=D", "?M=A", "?S=A", "?D=A", "/transcripts/"]},
{"link": ["?N=D", "?M=A", "?S=A", "?D=A", "/transcripts/", "bottom.htm", "top.htm"]},
{"link": ["?N=A", "?M=A", "?S=A", "?D=D", "/", "_borders/", "_fpclass/", "_private/", "_themes/", "amc/", "atwt/", "aw/", "bb/", "days/", "gh/", "gl/", "images/", "oltl/", "passions/", "pc/", "resources/", "test/", "yr/"]},
{"link": ["?N=A", "?M=A", "?S=A", "?D=A", "/", "yr/", "test/", "resources/", "pc/", "passions/", "oltl/", "images/", "gl/", "gh/", "days/", "bb/", "aw/", "atwt/", "amc/", "_themes/", "_private/", "_fpclass/", "_borders/"]},
{"link": ["?N=A", "?M=A", "?S=D", "?D=A", "/", "_borders/", "_fpclass/", "_private/", "_themes/", "amc/", "atwt/", "aw/", "bb/", "days/", "gh/", "gl/", "images/", "oltl/", "passions/", "pc/", "resources/", "test/", "yr/"]},
{"link": ["?N=A", "?M=D", "?S=A", "?D=A", "/", "_private/", "images/", "amc/", "atwt/", "aw/", "bb/", "days/", "gh/", "gl/", "oltl/", "passions/", "pc/", "yr/", "resources/", "_fpclass/", "_borders/", "_themes/", "test/"]},
{"link": ["?N=D", "?M=A", "?S=A", "?D=A", "/transcripts/", "localresources/", "main/", "older/"]},
{"link": ["?N=D", "?M=A", "?S=A", "?D=A", "/transcripts/", "menuh.css", "menuh_main.css", "new3.css"]},
{"link": ["?N=D", "?M=A", "?S=A", "?D=A", "/transcripts/", "localresources/", "older/"]},
{"link": ["?N=D", "?M=A", "?S=A", "?D=A", "/transcripts/", "localresources/", "main/", "older/"]},
{"link": ["?N=D", "?M=A", "?S=A", "?D=A", "/transcripts/", "localresources/", "main/", "older/"]},
{"link": ["?N=D", "?M=A", "?S=A", "?D=A", "/transcripts/", "localresources/", "main/", "older/"]},
{"link": ["?N=D", "?M=A", "?S=A", "?D=A", "/transcripts/"]},
{"link": ["?N=D", "?M=A", "?S=A", "?D=A", "/transcripts/", "amc_menu.html", "atwt_menu.html", "aw_menu.html", "bb_menu.html", "city_menu.html", "classic_prime.html", "current_prime.html", "day_amc.html", "day_atwt.html", "day_aw.html", "day_bb.html", "day_bottom.html", "day_city.html", "day_days.html", "day_gh.html", "day_gl.html", "day_oltl.html", "day_passions.html", "day_pc.html", "day_sube.html", "day_yr.html", "days_menu.html", "gh_menu.html", "ghns_menu.html", "gl_menu.html", "home_gen.html", "menu.js", "menu_ie4.js", "menu_ie5.js", "menu_moz.js", "menu_ns4.js", "menu_op5.js", "menu_op6.js", "menu_style.txt", "pass_menu.html", "pc_menu.html", "plinks_menu.html", "sniffer.js", "style.js", "sube_menu.html", "yr_menu.html"]}]
```

Result #2:
When I start the crawl at a later stage, for example, from, http://tvmegasite.net/transcripts/amc/main, surprisingly I don't get a list of just the transcript urls but other junk along with it:

```
[{"link": ["?N=D", "?M=A", "?S=A", "?D=A", "/transcripts/amc/main/"]},
{"link": ["?N=D", "?M=A", "?S=A", "?D=A", "/transcripts/amc/main/", "adbannerinclude4.txt", "custom.js", "custom_orig.js", "exfile.htm", "exfileinclude.txt", "menu.txt", "webringsinclude.txt", "webringsinclude_copy(1).txt"]},
{"link": ["?N=D", "?M=A", "?S=A", "?D=A", "/transcripts/", "localresources/", "main/", "older/"]},
{"link": ["?N=A", "?M=A", "?S=A", "?D=D", "/transcripts/amc/", "1998transcripts.shtml", "1999transcripts.shtml", "2001transcripts.shtml", "2002transcripts.shtml", "2003transcripts.shtml", "2004transcripts.shtml", "2005transcripts.shtml", "2006transcripts.shtml", "2007transcripts.shtml", "2008transcripts.shtml", "2009transcripts.shtml", "2010transcripts.shtml", "2011transcripts.shtml", "2013transcripts.shtml", "_overlay/", "favicon.ico", "localresources/", "newtemplate.shtml"]},
{"link": ["?N=A", "?M=A", "?S=D", "?D=A", "/transcripts/amc/", "_overlay/", "localresources/", "favicon.ico", "newtemplate.shtml", "1999transcripts.shtml", "1998transcripts.shtml", "2013transcripts.shtml", "2001transcripts.shtml", "2011transcripts.shtml", "2007transcripts.shtml", "2008transcripts.shtml", "2009transcripts.shtml", "2006transcripts.shtml", "2005transcripts.shtml", "2004transcripts.shtml", "2003transcripts.shtml", "2010transcripts.shtml", "2002transcripts.shtml"]},
{"link": ["?N=A", "?M=D", "?S=A", "?D=A", "/transcripts/amc/", "_overlay/", "favicon.ico", "localresources/", "newtemplate.shtml", "1998transcripts.shtml", "2010transcripts.shtml", "1999transcripts.shtml", "2001transcripts.shtml", "2002transcripts.shtml", "2003transcripts.shtml", "2004transcripts.shtml", "2005transcripts.shtml", "2006transcripts.shtml", "2007transcripts.shtml", "2008transcripts.shtml", "2009transcripts.shtml", "2011transcripts.shtml", "2013transcripts.shtml"]},
{"link": ["?N=A", "?M=A", "?S=A", "?D=A", "/transcripts/amc/", "newtemplate.shtml", "localresources/", "favicon.ico", "_overlay/", "2013transcripts.shtml", "2011transcripts.shtml", "2010transcripts.shtml", "2009transcripts.shtml", "2008transcripts.shtml", "2007transcripts.shtml", "2006transcripts.shtml", "2005transcripts.shtml", "2004transcripts.shtml", "2003transcripts.shtml", "2002transcripts.shtml", "2001transcripts.shtml", "1999transcripts.shtml", "1998transcripts.shtml"]}]
```

Comment: Does [^https?:\/\/?tvmegasite.net(?:\/transcripts)?\/\w+\/main\/?(?:\d+\w+\.\w+)?$](https://regex101.com/r/oT7eV3/1) solve the problem?

Comment: No I tried that. It does not make a difference. I guess Scrapy is smart like that. @stribizhev

Comment: If the anchors `^$` aren't needed, take'em off. Also, `tvmegasite.net` should be `tvmegasite\.net`

Comment: @sln Hi, I did what you suggested, and have the same problems.  

`[{"link": ["?N=D", "?M=A", "?S=A", "?D=A", "/transcripts/", "localresources/", "main/", "older/"]},
{"link": ["?N=D", "?M=A", "?S=A", "?D=A", "/transcripts/", "menuh.css", "menuh_main.css", "new3.css"]},
{"link": ["?N=D", "?M=A", "?S=A", "?D=A", "/transcripts/"]},
{"link": ["?N=D", "?M=A", "?S=A", "?D=A", "/transcripts/", "localresources/", "main/", "older/"]},`
 etc.